# How to create form which references separate approval list

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, flow

I'm in the process of creating a form which users can use to request access to certain resources. Each resource has an assigned approval manager and I'm hoping it'd be possible reference this list and generate an approval email via Flow?

The form has been made using InfoPath and is currently embedded within a Sharepoint page.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

SC

Answer (score 0):

You could be able to assign certain field's values based on user's input. For example, if a user requests resource 1 then approval manager field is automatically filled in with the approval manager's contact information. That field can then be used by flow to contact the approval manager. To accomplish this I recommend

1. creating a field requesting the resource that the user would like to use
2. create data connection to list with approval manager information and be sure to include all information that you'll need to pull from that list in order to identify which approval manager is assigned that resource
3. create a rule for the field from item 1 above that runs when this field is filled out. The rule will set the *queryfield* (be sure to use the dropdown for queryfield and not datafield) for the data connection that identifies the approval manager. For example: if the approval manager list has a column called assigned resource then you would set the assigned resource field to equal the resource that the user requested. Then, on the rule you're creating, add the action to query that data connection.
4. You can now assign a field on your form with the queried information for the approval manager.
5. Create a field in your from called approval manager and set its default value to the contact information from the data connection you created in step 2. (Be sure to use the *datafield* section of the data connection) and locate the field that has the contact information for the approval manager.
6. now you can have flow contact the approval manager using the approval manager field from your infopath form. (if flow can't find the field you created you may have to make the field available as a column in sharepoint)